# Vaadin using SpringSecurity authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, vaadin, vaadin8

Currently learning Vaadin8+SpringBoot for [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/) made me wanna forget about HTML for a while. Anyways, all is good for some CRUD operations until I mixed in SpringSecurity in the project. Well, I've been searching for days now and no solution could fit in well with the expected requirements.

Expected output:

- **Vaadin8+SpringBoot+SpringSecurity**
- All in one project/module/artifact
- 2 `@SpringUI` (`MainUI` = "", `LoginUI` = "/login")
- Multiple `@SpringView`s contained by `MainUI`'s `ViewDisplay`

Limitations:

- No `login.html` (from the Vaadin's [demo backery app](https://bakery.demo.vaadin.com/login.html))
- No SpringMVC for login page
- No vaadin4Spring dependency
- Configurations done through annotations and not through XMLs

I know there's a way, I'm blocked how to progress on this. And if it's really not possible, need to understand as to why it isn't.

Comment: So you would like to see spring boot make your Vaadin login page? In short, I did the following in a recent project: Created one UI class, with a ViewAccessControl implemented to deny when not logged-in, instruct navigator to show my login view (access denied view, is a @SpringView) in that case.

Answer (score 1):

When you configure Spring Security, you need to allow anonymous access to the `/login` URL (either `login.html` if it is a non-vaadin form, or the login UI path if you want a separate UI for login). You also need to restrict access to the actual application UI. You also need to allow anonymous access to the static resources (i.e. `/VAADIN/**`).

The SecurityConfig in Bakery may give you a starting point. (Note: the starter or its parts cannot be redistributed as a code example or template)

There is a more detailed explanation [here](http://www.flowingcode.com/2017/10/implementing-spring-security-on-vaadin.html), though it only covers Vaadin and Spring Security integration (i.e. no spring-boot).

Comment: Wish there were a spring-boot version of this.